How to make a button round in kivy with screen manager
I need to make a button round for my main screen for this app I'm making but I cannot use the 'RoundedRectangle@Button' method because my code keeps throwing an error that screen manager only takes instances of screen (or something like that). I have also tried canvas with just Ellipse as I have shown below but that just gives me a square button with the ellipse only showing up when I click on the button after the corners of the rectangle change a different color. Also, the text doesn't show up when I use the ellipse in canvas. So, I was wondering how to fix this problem to just make the button round. I'm not sure if I have to override something with screen manager or just add a line of code with the ellipse canvas thing. Any help would be appreciated because I've been stuck on this for too long! Also I'm new to kivy so if I didn't explain anything properly just let me know! Thank you
Below is the code I currently have with the canvas ellipse where the ellipse for the button only shows up after I click the button:
Button:
        text: "Go"
        size_hint: (None, None)
        markup: True
        size: (140, 70)
        pos: (1010, 62)
        #pos_hint: {'x': 0.85, 'y': 0.05}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (255/255.0, 214/255.0, 92/255, 1)
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "correct" if answer.text == "R" else "tryA"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

